# Create external link in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url

I know there are a lot of utility and helper classes/methods for generating URLs and links from internal routes and controllers.  But how would you tackle the below in MVC 3?

In a razor file someone has defined this:

```
<a href="http://@Model.Details.ExternalURL" target="_blank">Website</a>
```

`ExternalURL` in this instance will hold values like `www.yoursite.com`, without any prefixes.  Hard-coding an `http://` at the start is an obvious no-no but how best to handle this?

Comment: Why is hard-coding *http* bad?

Comment: I would make EternalULR a fully qualified url string.   Then <a href=@Model.Details.ExternalURL target="_blank">Website</a>

Comment: @dbaseman-- maybe not _bad_, but I'd like to have some flexibility in case its an https connection needed.  Forty-Two has a good idea, I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so bad to hardcode http:// in your case, but if you want to avoid it, I see few options, but maybe most correct will be to extend your model with property @Model.Details.ExternalUrlLink or something like that. In getter you can do any logic what you want over original value, e.g. concatenate http:// prefix if it's not presented